# Visual Studio Configuration Manager x64 only option

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, 64-bit, configurationmanager

I seem to have completely the *emphasized text*opposite*emphasized text* problem to everyone else... 
I'm trying to have my program (C++/CLI - Visual Studio 2010) run on any machine - but it's only working on 64 bit machines...

I checked my Configuration Manager and when I try and choose a new platform, "x64" is the only one that exists?

There is no other option - and I'm a bit stuck for ideas :(

Comment: The install obviously didn't go well.  You could randomly try that again.  After running a check on disk health and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration manager, for each project it lists the Platform (x86, x64, etc.).  Just because the project is set to a certain platform in the Configuration manager, doesn't mean the project is *actually* targeting that platform.

Instead, the platform selected in the configuration manager, means it will build that project according to the build settings selected for that platform.  So, if (for a given project) in the configuration you have selected "Any CPU", you need to go to that project's build settings (RMB on project->Properties->Build) Choose the Platform "Any CPU" in the top drop down to see the build settings for that platform.  Then, you'll notice lower down there is a "Platform target:" drop down.  *That* is the setting that decides what platform is targeted when you build this Configuration/Platform.

So you could actually set it up so that when you build using "Any CPU", that it is building targetting x64.

Make sense?

Comment: I think I get what you're saying - but I can't find the menu you're talking about? I right click the project -> Properties... And I come to a page with in the left hand side "Common Properties" and "Configuration Properties", none of which has a sub-menu "Build"?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was looking at a C# project.  Let me look at one of my C++/cli projects and see the difference.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: It looks that for C++/CLI, that in order to to accomplish "Any CPU" type behavior, you need to (a) compile as /clr:safe (Project Settings->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Common Language RunTime Support), (b) Set the CLR Image Type to "Force Safe IL Image" (Project Settings->Configuration Properties->Linker->Advanced->CLR Image Type).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31zwwc39

Comment: When I do this, and then try to compile - it throws 13369 (wow) errors saying stuff like "va_list *": this type is not verifiable (in vadefs.h) - which is a system file of some type I'm guessing? (It's not mine)

Comment: If you're using any code which can't be compiled as /clr:safe, then I think you're out of luck--you'll have to create dlls specific to the platform.

Comment: Well I'm not sure it's my code that's the problem? It's complaining about all of these files that I have nothing to do with...?