# Multiple/Division dilemma in equation

Tags: c++, c

I need to compute this equation in C/C++:

```
x=(a*b-1)/c;
```

with a,b,c,x of type __int64 (a,b,c,x<10^13). In all cases, a,b,c is select to make x fit in __int64.
However, a*b is very big that cause overflow and x is wrong.
I try to seperate a*b by typecasting:

```
x=(__int64)(((double)a/c)*(double)b - 1.0/c);
```

This way, a/c is computed first and overflow error not occur.
However, the problem is ((double)a/c)*(double)b sometimes have great value (about billions) and precision is reduced, so 1.0/c (very small) don't take any effect and cause an error within +-1.

For example: (__int64)(((double)a/c)*(double)b=123456789.01 is more likely to become 123456789.0 and 1.0/c=0.02. In this case, there is an error of +1.

Is there any way to compute x precise without external library such as Boost or Bignum? Even with error +-1 can screw up my code.
Thanks in advance.
By the way, I use Visual Studio 10.

Comment: perform 128-bit arithmetic as four 32-bit digits? It's not _that_ hard. Or even Assembler: `MOV, MUL, long decrement, DIV`.

Comment: They (VC et alia) don't have `int128` yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement the long arithmetic by hand, work with 32-bit blocks:

Long multiplication:

```
  (ax + b) * (cx + d)
= ac x^2 + (ad+bc) x + bd

  [ab]*[cd]=[efg]:

   //long long e,f,g
   g = (long long)b*d;
   f = (long long)a*d+b*c;
   e = (long long)a*c;
   //perform carry
   f += g>>32; g &= 0xFFFFFFFF
   e += f>>32; f &= 0xFFFFFFFF
```

School division, assuming unsigned arithmetic:

```
   [efg]/[hi]=[jkl]:

    [jk] = [ef]/[hi];
    r = [ef]-j*[hi];
    l = [rg]/[hi];
    if j > 0, result doesn't fit
    x = [kl];
```

If `a` and `b` are signed, fix the sign first and compute with absolute values, as suggestd by @Serge:
if a or b is zero, `x=(-1)/c`
otherwise, `sign(x)=sign(a)*sign(b)*sign(c)`

Comment: I originally wrote this as an algorithm rather than implementation. [ab] means a*2^32+b (concatenation in base-2^32)

Comment: @user1704182 please check the first part - i fixed one 'bug'

Comment: @Serge I used 'long' as "two 32-bit words", not 'long' in the C++ sense ;-)

Comment: @Jan any `long` being shifted 32 bits right in a result will produce 0. and you will lose the carry during computations. so e,f,g has to be `long long` (or whatever type in VC stands for 64 bit integer)

Comment: @Serge If `long` is 32 bits, yes. The C++ spec doesn't specify any fixed length except it may not be shorter than `int`. I specify 64 bits.

Comment: You may want to change this `f = (long long)a*d+b*c;` to this `f = (long long)a*d+(long long)b*c;`. Otherwise, you're risking an overflow in `b*c`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze It might actually be beneficial to have all variables `long long`s. But now I realise that (a*d+b*c) might actually be 65 bits and and it is neccessary to carry each half separately.

Comment: One problem is r may be large enough to become 64 bit and [rg]=[yzg]. In such case l=[yzg]/[hi]. We come back to original problem

Comment: @user1704182 Good point. start with `e/[hi]`. If `e/[hi]` is zero, `[ef]/[hi]` is 32-bit.

Comment: For some reason, if [ef] less bit,e.g.34 bit than [hi],e.g. 36 bit, then the remainder is [ef], and [efg] is 66 bit

Comment: @user1704182 ouch. It seems you'll have to handle 96-bit remainders as well. It's still `find the divisor such that the remainder is positive and less than the dividend`. As a last resort, you could calculate the result bit by bit, literally. This is a bit slower but easier to implement. Long comparison and subtraction. I'm actually starting to think bitwise division _is_ the best way, the "good old" shift and compare.

Comment: Edit (too late): `find the quotient such that the remainder is positive and less than the divisor`

Answer (score 2):

If your code can be CPU dependent, the easiest method might be to use assembler to retain the high-order 8 bytes. x64, assumes the result fits in 8 bytes:

```
__asm{
  MOV RAX, a
  MUL b
  SUB RAX, 1
  SBB RDX, 0
  DIV c
  MOV x, RAX
}
```

[1] http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic

Comment: When I add this code, the complier complaint: error C2415: improper operand type, at 2 lines contain RAX. I think VS don't allow RAX.

Comment: Are you building this for 64 bit target?

Comment: @user1704182 even if you specify the target CPU?

Comment: @user1704182 Check the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio for the build target; cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343814/visual-studio-configuration-manager-x64-only-option

Comment: So you want to target a 32-bit machine? Then my code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out maximum multiplier for a, which dosn't do overflow. For example if a*4 would make an overflow, then do it partially:

```
(a*5) = (a*3) + (a*2)
```

so if you find medium values like

```
b1, b2, b3, where b1+b2+b3 == b
```

then

```
x = a*b1/c + a*b2/c + a*b3/c - 1.0/c
```

you will find the biggest available value from b1 = floor(MAX_INT / a) then b2 will be the rest of b only if b-b1 < b1 if not you will have to repeat.

Comment: floating-point arithmetic could introduce off-by-one errors. `1.0/c` looks like a floating-point arithmetic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may just be able to rearrange your calculation:

```
x = (a*b - 1) / c
  = a*b/c - 1 / c
  = (a/c)*b - 1 / c       ;If a is likely to be huge
  = a*(b/c) - 1 / c       ;If b is likely to be huge
```

The problem would be loss of precision. This can be minimised by tracking the ranges of values and introducing scaling factors (chosen to make intermediate values as large as possible without overflow).

For an example, if `a` may be from 0 to 1024, `b` may be from 0 to 16777215 and `c` may be from 4096 to 8192; then:

```
x  = (a * ((256*b) /c) - 256 / c) / 256
```

In this case `(256*b) <= 0xFFFFFF00` (as large as possible to avoid overflowing a 32-bit unsigned integer), `( (256*b) / c) <= 0x000FFFFF`, and `a * ((256*b) /c) <= 0x3FFFFC00`.

Also for this case, `a*b` (from the original formula) would have overflowed a 32-bit unsigned integer; and `b/c` (from the first rearrangement) would have lost 8 bits of precision more than `(256 * b) / c` does.

Of course the best formula (the one that gives the least precision loss without overflow) for your specific case depends on the possible ranges of variables in your specific case.